# How to resolve generic types in C#

Tags: c#, generics

If I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IQuery<out TResult>
{
}

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle<TResult>(TQuery query);
}

public interface IDispatcher
{
    TResult Query<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
    TResult Query<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query);
}
```

and I then implement `IDispatcher` as follows:

```
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    // Insert IoC container of your choice here:
    // I've tried StructureMap, SimpleInjector and Grace so far,
    // they all have the same issue
    private readonly Container _container;    

    public TResult Query<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query) where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        var handler = _container.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>();
        return handler.Handle(query);
    }

    public TResult Query<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handler = _container.Resolve<IQueryHandler<IQuery<TResult>, TResult>();
        return handler.Handle(query);
    }
}
```

The first method works OK when I register my query handler instances using open generics:

```
var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
var results = dispatcher.Query<TestQuery, TestResult>(new TestQuery());
```

but if I use the less-wordy version:

```
var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
var results = dispatcher.Query(new TestQuery());
```

then the container fails to resolve the type - it can't go from `IQuery<TestResult>` and find an implementation of `IQueryHandler<IQuery<TestResult>, TestResult>`, while it can go from `TQuery where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>` and find an implementation of `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>`. So I'm guessing I'm bumping up against the limits of what generics can do in C#, but is there a way that I can get my second example to work without explicitly stating the query type and response type?

Update: Proof of concept [available here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5pwesqfrr1n0m7/cqrs-ioc.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example? This currently omits how you have set up the Container and attached it to the Dispatcher, among other things. My bet right now is on a registration existing for IQueryHandler<TestQuery,SomeResultType> and no registration existing for IQueryHandler<IQuery<SomeQueryType>,SomeResultType>.

Comment: Proof of concept, using 3 different IOC containers, attached.

Comment: It sounds like this is more likely to be an IoC container limitation than pure C#, and each container may well handle it differently. I would limit your question to a single container (whichever you most want to use) and specify that in the tag.

Comment: So if we focus just on StructureMap, how do I do register all query handlers as IQueryHandler<IQuery<TResult>, TResult>? Just doing your typical open generic registration IQueryHandler<,> doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Hmm, looking at similar questions on SO, it seems StructureMap has relatively limited support for complex generic registrations, and the recommendation is to use Simple Injector instead - is that advice still current, or has StructureMap improved since then? (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010964/structuremap-and-nested-generics)

Comment: I guess the question also becomes - why does the statement IQueryHandler<IQuery<SomeModel>, SomeModel> handler = new TestQueryHandler(); compile, when TestQueryHandler implements the original IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult> ?